# Testing multitasking iOS 9 feature in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, ios9, multitasking

I am using **XCode 7 (Beta)** to test multitasking, but I could not get a way to test with it.

I just want to make sure is there anyone like me, who facing the same issue.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using the an iOS9 simulator?

Comment: Yes, i am using ios9 simulator, however i am not able to see any settings related multitasking which supposed to be at "Settings > General > Multitasking".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You can test it.**

Just run ios simulator iPad Air 2 (ios 9)( because only this device supports Split View) and swipe from right to left near of middle edge of the screen

[image: See my screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your effort but may i know which Xcode version you have ?

Comment: @virus I have XCode 7 beta 4 (7A165t)

Comment: @virus And I don't have field Settings > General > Multitasking too in this version. But my app works fine

Comment: Thanks but it quoted by apple for the same. Please refer below link
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015145-CH13-SW1

Answer (score 4):

To adopt **Multi-Tasking** in your app, just make sure all below points followed:

- Require `XCode 7 (Beta 4)` and later for having look in to the simulator through choosing iPad Air 2 because only this device supports Split View.
- Provide a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file ( instead of a `.png` image file as we did in `iOS 7` and earlier).
- In your project’s `Info.plist` file, in the “Supported interface orientations (iPad)” array, declare support for all four device orientations.
- If you must opt out of Slide Over and Split View, do so explicitly by adding the `UIRequiresFullScreen` key to your Xcode project’s `Info.plist` file and apply the Boolean value `YES`. You can do this in the property list editor or in the `General > Deployment` Info area in the target editor.
- Select storyboard, click the File Inspector icon in the right side bar. check the box next to Use Size Classes.

[Reference Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015145-CH13-SW1)

Comment: Will a `LaunchScreen.xib` file suffice?

Comment: Found out that it will. Your 4th point about `UIRequiresFullScreen` helped me a lot. We had that set to `YES`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To adopt Multi-Tasking in your app. apply the following points:

1. Support all orientation from the target's General section in settings.
2. In the General section too. remove the check next to `Requires full screen` if any.
3. Select storyboard, click the File Inspector icon in the right side bar. check the box next to `Use Size Classes`. Check out tutorials how to use size class to adjust your views according to the screen size assigned to your app.

> Then, run the simulator. Do a small drag from the right. An arrow will
>   appear. do a strong drag from it towards the centre.